# Worklight Session variables Vs Global variables

Tags: variables, session, ibm-mobilefirst, global

I am working on Worklight adapters. I want data to be accessible across different requests and the data is related to the logged in user. I observed this can be achieved through session variables as well as global variables. But, I am not clear about the difference between these two. Kindly let me know the difference between these two, also please suggest which one to be implemented (Session variable or global variables)?

Comment: 1) Please always mention the version of Worklight that you are using. 2) Where did you read about this observation of session variables and global variables?

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar, for your quick reply and it helped my work. Here my answers for your quires, 1) my Worklight version is 6.0, 2) observed from my app

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are implemented internally by using the session object. This is why data stored in a global variable in your adapter logic can be used in follow-up requests, in the same session that the original request initiated.

Session variables are a feature of the server (Apache, Liberty and so on...).

Usage-wise, a global variable is available only to the specific adapter it was declared in, whereas a session variable is available across any code running on that server.

Should be noted, that if running MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 and creating a *new* app, this app and server are running in a session-independent mode, meaning that global variables and session variable cannot be relied on. You will need to use an external source such as a database to store the data (that is "global").